# System Center Essentials question

Tags: windows-server-2008, system-center

Hopefully quick question...

I have an AD environment with an empty forest-root and then a child domain that all the users and computers are in.

I've just installed SCE and I did it at the domain level. Now I want to add the 3 AD servers in the parent/top level forest and I while I can connect to them and add them to the inventory by using the proper creds, I am not able to get any more info from those machines.

How do I get the domain-level GPO on the forest-level and get access to inventory and do patching.

Thanks in advance...Michael